# fgets() works wrong in for loop

Tags: c, char, newline, fgets, fputs

I am trying to use `fgets` and `fputs` to copy-paste a file. I wrote in two ways, one in for loop, the other in while loop. While loop works perfectly, but for loop acts weird.

I tried to debug and wrote this:

```c
FILE *infile = fopen("infile", "r");
FILE *outfile = fopen("forLoop_outfile", "w");
int row = 6, len = 6;
char *readbuf = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    printf(" %d ", i);
    if (fgets(readbuf, len, infile) == NULL)
       perror("fgets");
    if (fputs(readbuf, outfile) == -1)
       perror("fputs");
    if (fputs(readbuf, stdout) == -1)
       perror("fputs");
}
```

input file:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
z
```

stdout and output file are the same:

```
 0 abcde 1 
 2 fghij 3 
 4 klmno 5
```

as you can see, only the first 3 lines are read, and something when wrong for every 2 iteration. And debugging seems useless.

What's going wrong?

Comment: I suspect your file has `\r\n` line breaks.

Comment: Read the manual page for `fgets()` : since there is not enough space for the terminating '\n', it will be read in a next call to `fgets()` (solution: use a larger buffer and strip the LF)

Comment: Make `len` bigger and it should work.

Comment: @wildplasser Got it!!! I need 5 + 1(`\n`) + 1(`\0`)  = 7 characters to make it work. I guess it will make `\0` compulsory, so it has no space for `\n`. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Also: `fputs() writes the string s to stream, without its terminating null byte ('\0')` and it does **not** add a '\n'. [it is all in the fine manual]

Comment: @wildplasser I will read the manual again, thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the input file contains

```
abcde\n
fghij\n
klmno\n
pqrst\n
uvwxy\n
z\n
```

As the length of the dynamically allocated array is equal to `6` then the first call of `fgets` reads only `5` characters `"abcde"` and appends them with the terminating zero character `'\0'`. The new line character `'\n'` is not read yet. So the next call of `fgets` reads this new line character `'\n'`.

To resolve the problem enlarge the size of the dynamically allocated array.

Comment: This happens over and over again with beginner's code: they allocate the tiniest amount of buffer space that they imagine will be enough, but miscalculate.

Comment: And one moral of the story is: when reading lines, don’t skimp on the space allocated.  Consider a buffer of 2048 bytes as a minimum; you can go bigger if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int row = 6, len = 10;
char *readbuf = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    printf(" %d ", i);
    if (fgets(readbuf, len, infile) == NULL)
    {
       perror("fgets");
       break;
    }
    if (fputs(readbuf, outfile) == -1)
       perror("fputs");
    if (fputs(readbuf, stdout) == -1)
       perror("fputs");
}
```

Your `len`is too small as you have also '\n' char at the end.
You need to stop the execution if you failed to read the new line.